# Ireport populating data horizontally

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to show project names vertically and the next name should come next to the first one in ireport.
Its similar to rotating the normal output to 90 degree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate text fields by 90 degrees in jasper reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016091/how-to-rotate-text-fields-by-90-degrees-in-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 0):

Set the report layout to horizontal layout.