# How to rotate text fields by 90 degrees in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating some reports using iReport designer. While generating reports I came across a requirement where I have to display static text fields/labels in 90 degree rotation as shown in the below image:

[image: 90 degree rotated text field]

I was searching on internet to get solution for this and I came to know that jaspersoft doesn't support text field rotation. I read this in the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665663/watermark-across-the-page-in-jasperreports). Is this feature available in any new version of jaspersoft?
Or is there any way to achieve this functionality using external java programs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate column text by 60 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230552/rotate-column-text-by-60-degrees)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jasper report does not support the rotation at a certain degree, but your example is rotation="Left", so to rotate the text you should use the rotation property on the textElement example

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="100" y="2" width="100" height="75" uuid="ac56467b-05e7-4749-ab0a-cf15b3c2047d"/>
    <textElement rotation="Left">
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[YOUR TEXT]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Where the key code is `<textElement rotation="Left">`

The rotation can have these propreties.

`Left` = As in you example text goes from down to up

`Right` = Text goes from up to down

`UpsideDown` = Text is upside down

If you are using iReport check out the properties tab > Text properties > Rotation

Comment: Here is my code : <staticText>
       <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="5" width="70" height="25" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="0696b52c-76ef-46ef-a7f5-d5edffd1177f"/>
       <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFA500"/>
       </box>
       <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Right" markup="styled">
        <font isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
       </textElement>
       <text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
      </staticText>

Comment: I use iReport. Thanks for the complete step.